# How do i prove the formula for the volume of a cone?

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d

I need a general proof for any form of a cone, not a right circular one.

Comment: Define what you know about your non-right circular cone. What does this mean?

Comment: http://exploration.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/volume.html

Comment: thanks, everyone. And, in a non-right circular cone or an oblique cone, the angle between the line joining the apex to the center of the base circle and the radius of the base circle is not a right angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the base has area $a$ and the cone has height $h$, measured perpendicular to the base.  Choose a system of coordinates, so that the cone point is at $z = 0$, and the altitude meets the base at $z = h$.  In general, the cross section at arbitrary $z$ is a figure similar to the base with area
$$
A(z) = a \left( \frac{z}{h} \right)^2.
$$

Now integrate to find the volume.
$$
\begin{align}
V &= \int_0^h A(z) \, dz \\
&= \int_0^h a \frac{z^2}{h^2} \, dz \\
&= \left. \frac{a}{h^2} \frac{z^3}{3} \right|_0^h \\
&= \frac{ah}{3}.
\end{align}
$$